# do we need weak or unowned reference when doing a lazy variable, memory management

Tags: swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, lazy-evaluation

I'm experimenting with memory management in Swift by following.

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    //var block: (() -> Void)?

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    //  Declare variable clone, using self inside.
    private lazy var clone: String  = {
        return self.name   
    }()

    deinit {
        print("Destroying \(name)")
    }
    func doSomething() {
        print("Doing something for \(name)")
    }
}

var p2: Person? = Person(name: "p2")
print(p2!.clone)
p2 = nil
```

As you see, I'm using `self` inside when declaring a lazy var and I think it is still ok because when p2 is getting nil, I can see the `deinit` method get called.

However, if I make a change like following

```
    // This is a closure
    private lazy var clone: () -> String  = {
        return self.name    // leaking memory is here
    }
```

Now, I am getting a leaking memory.

My question is for a variable using lazy instantiation, why I don't get a leaking memory even though I am using `self`.I thought I had to use it otherwise I would get a leaking memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you leak memory is because closure will capture self strongly in default and at the same time self hold the closure as a property strongly. It has nothing to do with lazy variable.

Comment: that is what I thought before posting.I want to make sure my thought is right.Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Here :

```
 private lazy var clone: () -> String  = {
        return self.name    // leaking memory is here
    }
```

You are assigning the closure itself to the variable, instead of assigning the `String` that it is supposed to return. And since you're using `self` which the closure **retains**, the two will never be released which can lead to a `memory leak`. A `reference cycle` is created as the closure is retained as a property and the closure retains self. Here is where the `capture lists` come into picture. You can fix the leak like so:

```
private lazy var clone: () -> String  = { [unowned self] in

        return self.name    // leaking memory is fixed
    }
```

`Self` is declared as `unowned` in the `capture lists` as it is safe to assume that it will **NOT** be `nil` at any point. If you are sure the variable will **NEVER** be `nil`, use `unowned` but if you think at some point it *might* become `nil`, use `weak` instead.